# Process crash and History stack

Tags: android

We have an Android app that consists of about 20 activities. Whenever there is a crash in the process due to an uncaught exception or crash in a native routine and the user chooses to "Force close" the process, only the activity in foreground is finished and taken off the History Stack.

It is my assumption that when the process is killed, all the activities in the History stack should go down as well? What could be the issue here or am I missing something?

Anyone else observed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is my assumption that when the process is killed, all the activities in the History stack should go down as well?

More accurately, all of the process' activities in the task would go away.

> What could be the issue here or am I missing something?

You are assuming that when there is "an uncaught exception or crash in a native routine and the user chooses to 'Force close'" that this kills the process.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for your reply. You meant process' correct? All the activities belonging to the task that a user was performing will go away?
The second is surprise; I always thought it killed the process, will check.

Comment: @Samuh: "You meant process' correct?" -- yes, sorry. I have fixed that typo.